# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action()

Tags: errors, wp-redirect, fatal-error

I'm working with WP Engine and added their geotarget add on and my redirect is working when I use my VPN in anywhere outside the U.S. which is what I want. However, when I test within the U.S. I get...

"www.[mysite].com redirected you too many times." 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'.

I receive the following error when texting the PHP code:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /tmp/12qky4434krkkmq50/tester.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /tmp/12qky4434krkkmq50/tester.php on line 11

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
function country_geo_redirect() {
$country = getenv('HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
if ( $country == 'US' ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.[mysite].com', 301 );
exit;
}else if ( $country !== ( 'US' ) ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://[eu.mysite].com', 301 );
exit;
}}
add_action('init', 'country_geo_redirect');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First I think that `init` is to high for a redirect, maybe try using `template_redirect` or `wp`. Second, if a user came to `https://www.[mysite].com` and he is from the US, he will be redirected to `https://www.[mysite].com` (a never ending loop)

Comment: Try using cookies that expire daily to check if a user is "new", if "new" redirect and set the cookie. If cookie exists user is not "new" and should not be redirected

Comment: is this PHP script even loading WordPress?  It appears that you've just created a PHP script and you're calling it directly? If so, then that's the problem. You can't use WordPress functions from within a completely independent PHP file that you call directly that doesn't include the WordPress load.

Comment: Thank you all. I ended up finding someone to help with this that recoded it and all is working as it should.